# Mac OS X showWindow problem: NSWindow appears only once

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a Mac OS X program visible only in status bar that must show a preferences window.
I have this IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)showPreferences:(id)sender {
    [self.preferencesWindowController showWindow:self];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

In applicationDidFinish Lauching I have:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Load the app's preferences window (but does not display it)
    self.preferencesWindowController = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferencesWindowController"];

    [...]

}
```

The class header:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppPref.h"


@interface PreferencesWindowController : NSWindowController {
}

@end
```

The problem is: the preference window shows up only once. When I close it, it will never reappear anymore.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the window properties so that it is not destroyed when it is closed.  You can do this in Interface Builder.

As an alternative, I recommend loading the nib from the `-showPreferences:` method.  Loading the nib in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method will slow down your application launch time with no benefit to the user or your code.

Comment: You mean "Release When Closed" checkbox. I have de-checked and nothing better happens.

Comment: I have found a solution: I forgot to connect the window outlet, connecting it solves my problem.

Comment: He meant the second thing you did - I just went through the same exercise, and am finding many posts with the same issue. If so many people have trouble with this issue, it screams for Apple to make it easier to do.